# When trying to run react-bootstrap or just react in general I always get events.js:287 and other errors as shown bellow

Tags: reactjs

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JoseH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-08T20_10_31_948Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

This is always what comes up and im not sure what to do in order to fix this problem, im fairly new to using react and I want to know what I can do in order to fix this problem. I tried clearing the cache using npm but that didnt work. Im not sure how to change the port that is being used but if someone can help me with that, I feel like that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your package.json for a start key with value as react-scripts start

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start", //as its here
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --coverage --coverageDirectory=output/coverage/jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

If its not there change it to as its shown above

If it still doesnt work, run

```
npm install
```

If it still stays..try to clean the cache using this

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it still gave me the same error, but thank you for trying I appreciate it

Comment: Do u have react-scripts installed globally? If not try running this: npm install -g react-scripts